# Selecting data from multiple tables using regexp in postgres or any SQL platform

Tags: sql, regex

Is there a way to select from multiple tables using regexp in postgres or any SQL platform?

I want to select data from all tables in the database provided the table names follow a pattern.

I attempted the following but without any success...

```
SELECT cpu_id,date,time,duration,state,speed
FROM like 'count%' ","where date = '2012-09-27'
```

The table names are `count1`, `count2` and so on. I want to take all of them.

I am sorry, I do not know how to put a reproducible example/data in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that. Tables are meant to hold different rows and data. Have you considered merging the tables (instead, place some sort of index instead of different table names)?